# If Macro cannot find attachment do not create email and move to next row

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry I am very new to VBA. I have a vba that creates a email, attaches a file to the email, and sends it. It works perfectly if the file is present in the folder. My problem is there may not always be a file to attach. This is a daily email and 1 recipient will be on today's email list but not tomorrows.

So I have a list of vendors. I would like the VBA to go through each row of the list. Create the email, attached the file, and send the email. For the most part the VBA works. Expect for when the file is not in the folder. If the file is not in the folder I would like the VBA to continue to the next row and not stop.

```
Sub sendEmailWithAttachments()

Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
row = 2
col = 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "message.oft")
    Set myAttachments = OutLookMailItem.Attachments
    'Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col))
        With OutLookMailItem
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value = "xxxFINISHxxx" Then
                'MsgBox ("Exiting...")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "To" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                .To = .To & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "Cc" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                .CC = .CC & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "Bcc" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
                .BCC = .BCC & "; " & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "attachment" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
              myAttachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "xxxignorexxx" Then
                ' Do Nothing
            Else
                .Subject = Replace(.Subject, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value)
                'Write #1, .HTMLBody
                .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody, ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value, ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value)
                'ActiveSheet.Cells(10, 10) = .HTMLBody
            End If

            'MsgBox (.To)
        End With
        'Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)

        col = col + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select

    Loop
    OutLookMailItem.HTMLBody = Replace(OutLookMailItem.HTMLBody, "xxxNLxxx", "<br>")
    OutLookMailItem.Send
    col = 1
    row = row + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try: `MsgBox Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value` and see what do you get? Write this on the line, after `With OutLookMailItem`.

Comment: Thank you. But that did not work. It only gave me a message box with the file path name.

Comment: That was the idea. How does the path name look like? Is there something strance after the last `\` sign? E.g. an error or something in `.Cells(row,col).Value`

Comment: the file path name looks good. It is the correct path.

Comment: Have you used an On Error statement?  You would create a contingency directly above the line which may cause the error.  The On Error statement applies to the line directly after it is written.

Comment: @Cyril Just clarifying: The On Error statement applies to all lines after it in the sub in which it's declared. If you only want the On Error statement to apply to a specific line, after that line, you need another: `On Error goto 0` to revert back to the auto-error catching.

Comment: Can an On Error goto be used in this code to move to the next row in the sheet and continue the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

First: declare a new variable

```
Dim sFile As String
```

Then: replace

```
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "attachment" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
          myAttachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
```

With:

```
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(1, col).Value = "attachment" And Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) Then
            If Not Dir(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value) = "" Then
                myAttachments.Add Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Value
            Else
                MsgBox "Please, select a file."
                sFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
                If Not sFile = "" Then
                    myAttachments.Add sFile
                End If
            End If
```

Comment: That did not seem to work either. Do you have a suggestion on where the line should be added? Sorry again, very new to this.

Comment: That is what I am looking for thanks! But there will be times when I do not have a file to select at all. How do I stop the VBA from creating an empty email and move to the next row in the sheet?

Comment: Just click 'Cancel' in FileDialogPicker window. Your mail will not include any attachment. If you don't need any dialog windows in your macro use code in my second answer.

Comment: It all works. However, if there isn't an attachment I don't want to create the email at all.

Comment: Could you attach an example file?

Comment: AMAZING! Works like a charm. Thank you so much!